# Why javascript is not working on safari?

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

I am developing a website with has a header as (channels,...) and the header is working fine in all the browser except safari. The code is work fine on chrome as well still i facing the issue on safari browser. Is there anything which i missed in the code specified in the link.  I also tried with the code to fetch browser and write a separate code for it but it also not works for me. Should anybody help me how to fix it. What i have already tried is : http://www.code-dynamix.com/blazemedia/services-channels.html

Problem exist at the Second header (Channels,...) where slider comes little bit down in safari.For better clarification just see the same header in any other browsers such as firefox, chrome and then see the header in safari.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm seeing like 2 different versions of jQuery in there?

Comment: What have you tried? What's the relevant code? This question is way too vague.

Comment: Works ok on safari for me (v7.0 on mac) - same as chrome.

Comment: my safari version is 6.0.3 on mac

Comment: It would be helpful if you included images of the rendering issue so that folks don't have to open the link in three browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript works fine for me in Safari 5.1.7 on Windows 7, but there are differences with how the header is rendered. This is an issue with CSS however. As best I can tell, there are no defined heights on any of the containing elements. You should define the heights when you can, this will help keep a universal look and feel.